# How to get a list of IDs not present in a (My)SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table, that looks like this:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| a  |
| c  |
| e  |
+----+
```

I want to check which of the following ids `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` does not exist in the table.

Meaning, I want to get a list of the ids `b` and `d` back.

Is there a single query I can construct by hand that returns a list of IDs that does not exist in my table, without actually creating a new second permanent SQL table?

Comment: using Which RDBMS...?

Comment: As the title and the question specified; MySQL =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually done using a `left join` or something like this:

```
select ids.id
from (select 'a' as id union all select 'b' union all select 'c' union all
      select 'd' union all select 'e'
     ) ids
where ids.id not in (select id from t);
```

If the list is already in a table, then you can use that table (or subquery) instead of a derived table.